# Copy value from one hashmap to another

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, hashmap

I have two hashmaps

```
Map<String, Employee> employees
Map<String, Address> address
```

and Employee and Address classes look as follows:

```
class Employee {
 String name,
 String city
}

class Address {
 String city
}
```

How can I copy city value from "address" hashmap to a city in Employee object of 'employees' hashmap if keys between these two hashmaps (employees and address) matches?

I want to copy with functional java 8 declaratively without for loop.

Comment: Mutation isn't pragmatically functional. If you just wanna use a lambda instead of for loop, then just use a simple stream and foreach

Comment: you can iterate through the keyset of the `address` Map and verify if the `employees` Map contains the key, if it does, then just update the employee value accordingly. But before that, sharing what you've attempted would make more sense to all.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to manipulate `employees` map and if you just want to use lambdas for it, it can be done something like this assuming that the keys in both `employees` and `address` match:

```
address.entrySet().forEach(entry -> employees.get(entry.getKey()).setCity(entry.getValue().getCity()));
```

This can also be rewritten as

```
address.forEach((key, val) -> employees.get(key).setCity(val.getCity()));
```

without making use of `entrySet()`